# Clustering with bigkmeans from bigmemory package in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I recently started experimenting with the biganalytics package for R. I ran into a problem however...

I am trying to run `bigkmeans` with a cluster number of about 2000 e.g `clust <- bigkmeans(mymatrix, centers=2000)`

However, I get the following error:
`Error in 1:(10 + 2^k) : result would be too long a vector`

Can someone maybe give me a hint what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Vectors are limited by the type used for the index -- there is/was some talk about replacing this index type by a double but it hasn't happen yet and is unlikely as it may break so much existing code.

If your `k` is really large, you may not be able to do this the way you had planned.